# Sort index of different length tuples in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(index=[('B',),('A',),('B','C',),('A','B',),('A','B','C')],data=[1,2,3,4,5],columns=['count'])

>>> df
          count
(B,)        1
(A,)        2
(B, C)      3
(A, B)      4
(A, B, C)   5
```

I would like to sort by the tuple index such that the 1 length tuples are sorted, then the 2 length, etc. The expected output is this:

```
          count
(A,)        2
(B,)        1
(A, B)      4
(B, C)      3
(A, B, C)   5
```

I have tried sort_index, but that sorts according to the first member only and disregards the length:

```
>>> df.sort_index()
count
(A,)        2
(A, B)      4
(A, B, C)   5
(B,)        1
(B, C)      3
```

Comment: Not a direct answer but storing tupules in a pandas data frame is a bad idea (and recommended against in the documentation itself). It limits the df to python speeds and you also run into problems like this. The efficient way for this is to store list of lists (which would turn into a matrix).

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html

Answer (score 4):

You can also `reindex`:

```
print (df.reindex(sorted(df.index,key=lambda d: (len(d), d))))

           count
(A,)           2
(B,)           1
(A, B)         4
(B, C)         3
(A, B, C)      5
```

Comment: Nice answer using `reindex` and `sorted` with lambda.  +1

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you could do this by creating a sortkey:

```
(df.assign(sortkey=df.index.str.len())
   .rename_axis('index')
   .sort_values(['sortkey', 'index']))
```

Output:

```
           count  sortkey
index                    
(A,)           2        1
(B,)           1        1
(A, B)         4        2
(B, C)         3        2
(A, B, C)      5        3
```

First, let's use .str accessor to get the `len` of the tuple in the index and `assign` to a temporary column, sortkey.  Let's `rename_axis` the index so, we can then use `sort_values` using a combination of column headers and index name.